# sequelize afterConnect hook with mssql (tedious)

Tags: sql-server, sequelize.js, tedious

While trying to inject prepared statements with MSSQL (tedious) - once I'm trying to execute the request I'm getting the following error:

`Database connection failed: Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the SentClientRequest state`

The imports:

```js
import { Connection, Request } from 'tedious';
```

The hook:

```js
public static async afterConnect(connection, options): Promise<void> {
    const client = connection['resource'] as Connection;

    let request = new Request('select 42',(err, rowCount, rows) => {
      console.log(`${err} ${rowCount} rows`);
    });

    client.execSql(request);
  }
```

According to tedious I need to chain the request after the previous one, sequelize doesn't seem to pass that data, is there a way to work around this issue?

I've also created an issue on [Sequelize GitHub](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/12323)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

took some digging inside sequelize code, but found a work around - if anyone has a similar issue.

```js
public static async afterConnect(connection, options): Promise<void> {
    const mssql = connection as { resource: Connection; previous: Promise<unknown> };

    await new Promise((resolve) => {
      let request = new Request('select 42', (err, rowCount) => {
        logger.debug(method, `${err} - ${rowCount} rows`);

        resolve();
      });

      await mssql.previous; // failsafe?
      mssql.resource.execSql(request);
    });
}
```